# How to show the XtraReports Field List panel when it's closed?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtrareport

Maybe this is a newbie question or RTFM question... but I couldn't find it yet.

Once we have a schema in a XtraReport, the tool shows the Field List, which is a panel from we can add fields to our report, with the datasource setted. But there's cases where that field list is closed by whatever reason (for example, I just re-opened the project and the field list is gone), how I call that panel again? I've searched in the View menu, in toolbars and context menus in the report and couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open a report in design view, a menu item "XtraReports" appears. The needed menu items can be found here.

Comment: This answer is the best one - does not require closing open reports.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't see it using VS2008/DevExpress9.1.  All I see when I open a report in design view is:
File Edit View Project Build Debug Data Format Tools Test Window Help

Answer (score 1):

Try closing all reports that are opened in Design mode in Visual Studio.  Then re-open one.  Any designer windows that you've closed *should* re-appear.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the XtraReports menu item and there you will find the Field List item. Click it and it will re-appear .

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is in visual studio open the designer page.  in the menu bar, there is XTRAREPORTS field. You can show up panels using it